# Matlab -problems with randi

Tags: matlab

I tried to write a function called `random_square_deployment(n_nodes,square_length)` that generates
a bi-dimensional random deployment of wireless sensor nodes into a square sensing area. Here `n_nodes` is the number of nodes, the length of the square region delimiting the sensing area is in meters.

The function should return as output an n-by-2 matrix whose rows are the x and y coordinates of the sensor nodes. The origin, (0, 0), of the coordinates lies in the top-left (equivalently, north-west) vertex of the square region.

I have never done Matlab. I just tried to learn the basic today. Could someone help me by giving some instruction how to solve this?

```
function r = random_square_deployment(n_nodes,square_length)
m = 0 < n_nodes < square_length

n = randi([m],)
```

Comment: Define "random": which distribution? Uniform on a square? Statistically independent positions?

Comment: uniformly distributed random.Thanks

Comment: Then you only need `r = square_length*rand(n_nodes,2);`. See [rand](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html)

Comment: % problem 1.1 solution
function [n, s]= random_square_deployment(n_nodes, square_length)
% r = square_length * rand(n_nodes,2)
n  = n_nodes
s  =  square_length
if(0<n<s)
    A = zeros(s, s) 
    for n = 1: n
        i = randi(s)
        j = randi(s)
        A(i,j) = A(i,j)+1 %if one already existed add one more to i and j
      
    end
else
    disp ('invalid input') % raise an error
end
A % display matrix

end